# pyqt5 show which button was clicked

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qbuttongroup

I am new to PyQT5 and I want to have several buttons and have the one clicked last in a "checked" state. When another button is clicked the previous one gets "unchecked" while the clicked one gets "checked".

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(30, 30, 400, 200)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.button1 = QPushButton(self)
        self.button1.setGeometry(40, 40, 100, 50)
        self.button1.setText("Button 1")

        self.button2 = QPushButton(self)
        self.button2.setGeometry(150, 40, 100, 50)
        self.button2.setText("Button 2")

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use functools partial or the sender method to check which button was pressed:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from functools import partial
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(30, 30, 400, 200)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.button1 = QPushButton(self)
        self.button1.setGeometry(40, 40, 100, 50)
        self.button1.setText("Button 1")
        self.button1.clicked.connect(partial(self.clicked_btn, 'Button 1'))

        self.button2 = QPushButton(self)
        self.button2.setGeometry(150, 40, 100, 50)
        self.button2.setText("Button 2")
        self.button2.clicked.connect(partial(self.clicked_btn, 'Button 2'))

        self.show()

    def clicked_btn(self, value):
        print(f'{value} clicked')
        sender = self.sender()
        print(f'Sender says: {sender.text()} was clicked')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: this is an amazing solution as well. People need to vote this up!

Answer (score 5):

Building off of your code, you can add `button1` and `button2` to a `QButtonGroup` with the `exclusive` property set to `True`.

```
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(30, 30, 400, 200)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.button1 = QPushButton(self)
        self.button1.setGeometry(40, 40, 100, 50)
        self.button1.setText("Button 1")

        self.button2 = QPushButton(self)
        self.button2.setGeometry(150, 40, 100, 50)
        self.button2.setText("Button 2")

        self.btn_grp = QButtonGroup()
        self.btn_grp.setExclusive(True)
        self.btn_grp.addButton(self.button1)
        self.btn_grp.addButton(self.button2)

        self.btn_grp.buttonClicked.connect(self.on_click)

        self.show()

    def on_click(self, btn):
        pass # do something with the button clicked

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here I've also connected an empty slot to the signal `QButtonGroup.buttonClicked`, which is emitted whenever a button from the group is clicked.

To find out which button is the currently checked button, you can invoke the methods `QButtonGroup.checkedButton()` and `QButtonGroup.checkedId()`. The former will return a `QButton` object and the latter will return an index `int`, corresponding to the order in which the buttons were added to the group.

Comment: how do you call 'QButtonGroup.checkedButton()' from inside of "on_click" method? You are passing there QPushButton, so you can ask for btn.text() but how you check group from button itself ?

Comment: Good answer. It's worth mentioning that according to docs, [setExclusive](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#exclusive-prop) property defaults to True

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the buttons checkable by setCheckable(True)
2. Add the buttons to a QButtonGroup() and the rest is sorted automatically:

   ```
   class Example(QWidget):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.setGeometry(30, 30, 400, 200)
          self.initUI()

      def initUI(self):
          self.button1 = QPushButton(self)
          self.button1.setGeometry(40, 40, 100, 50)
          self.button1.setText("Button 1")
          self.button1.setCheckable(True)
          self.button2 = QPushButton(self)
          self.button2.setGeometry(150, 40, 100, 50)
          self.button2.setText("Button 2")
          self.button2.setCheckable(True)

          self.my_button_group = QButtonGroup()
          self.my_button_group.addButton(self.button1)
          self.my_button_group.addButton(self.button2)

          self.show()
   ```

Comment: Actually you are correct setting buttons to get checked while clicked will be used to understand which button is currently pushed by the user.